# nuxt/vue memory management and destroyed life cycle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory, nuxt.js

I have two page components and each one has two local data ... in "created" life cycle I assign some value to these data then I change route between these two pages ... from the memory tab in developer tool I can see heap memory size will increase with each route change but as far as I know vue should remove all data related to destroyed component but that's not the case here.

~/pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
  <nuxt-link to="/contact">contact</nuxt-link>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testArr: [],
      str: "...", //assign very large string 
    };
  },
  created() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      this.testArr.push({ //just to make this array as big as possible
        key1: this.str,
        key2: this.str,
        key3: this.str,
        key4: this.str,
        key5: this.str,
      });
    }
  },
  destroyed() {
    //although we are inside destroyed life cycle we can still access to 
    //this.str,this.testArr
    console.log("destroyed");
  },
};
</script>
```

~/pages/contact.vue:

```
<template>
  <nuxt-link to="/">home</nuxt-link>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testArr: [],
      str: "...", //assign very large string 
    };
  },
  created() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      this.testArr.push({ //just to make this array as big as possible
        key1: this.str,
        key2: this.str,
        key3: this.str,
        key4: this.str,
        key5: this.str,
      });
    }
  },
  destroyed() {
    //although we are inside destroyed life cycle we can still access to 
    //this.str,this.testArr
    console.log("destroyed");
  },
};
</script>
```

***if I add bellow code to both of these pages now memory will not increase but vue should release memory by itself and inside 'destoryed' life cycle 'this.<some-data' should be undefined:

```
beforeDestroy() {
    this.str = undefined;
    this.testArr = undefined;
  },
```

how can I optimize my app to release memory when component gets destroyed and not hold data related to the destroyed component in memory?

nuxt version "2.15.8"
vue version "2.6.14"

Comment: Strange that you have a memory leak here. Is it the only code that you have in a brand new Nuxt app? Also, did you tried to the check the value of the variable in `destroyed` after a `nextTick` just to be sure? I don't know if Vue is supposed to garbage collect the variables looking at the description here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#destroyed

Comment: yes it's totally new and empty nuxt project ... $nextTick() does not change anything and even after $nextTick()  inside destroyed life cycle I can access to my data

Comment: Did you check this with 3? I'm quite sure this is specific to Nuxt and not Vue in general. Also pages are not regular components, they can behave differently

Comment: vue3(without nuxt) is also behave similary means even inside 'unmounted' hook I can still access to 'this' and this.<some-data> gives me real data